# Node.js script to copy files overwriting previous ones?

Tags: node.js

I wish to create a Node.js script to copy files overwriting previous versions of the same files.
My code doesn't work:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var src = "srcPath/file.json";
    var newPath = "newPath/file.json";

    var callback = (result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }

    copy(src, newPath, callback);

function copy(src, newPath, callback){
    fs.copyFile(src, newPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            callback("Error Found:", err);
            }
        else {
            callback("Success: "+newPath);
        }
    });
}

execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, if you take this line off:

```
execute()
```